# mirror one CIFS SMB share to another CIFS SMB share using java (Only copy files which are newer or changed)

Tags: java, smb, cifs, jcifs

I have several SMB file utilities written, and can easily copy files from one cifs share to another cifs share using SMB.  Problem is I want to create a "mirror" method that will copy all files from one share to another that have changed or are new.  I am talking about a share with thousands of files and up to 4GB in size and this will run every 1/2 hour, so just copying every file would never work.  Anyone have ideas or know of an existing package in maven that would accomplish this?

Comment: Do not use Java. Do not write your own `rsync`. Just use [`rsync`](https://rsync.samba.org/). It's literally written for this use case.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch   Although Windows has come to encompass ssh, I'm not sure rsync (which is ssh-based) for Windows is yet a thing. If not, I'd be inclined to `ProcessBuilder` Windows xcopy. *Unless* of course there is no Windows here at all and the cifs, like mine, involves only a Linux server

Comment: Thought about that.  couple of issues, one, I am forced to use a remote Windows 11 server which doesn't allow rsync to be installed, thus is must be either a java method, or perhaps something in powershell.

Comment: xcopy through powershell might be an alternative.  It's been so darned long I forgot all about that.  Now to see if it exists on the build servers.

Comment: If they're Windows boxes, it definitely should. It's one of the old DOS apps still remaining

Comment: @g00se WSL is a thing. And a quick search shows rsync is supported on Windows. But fair enough. I would research existing solutions more exhaustively, before considering a (poor) reimplementation of rsync.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure and would be interested to know if rsync really works on Windows. Certainly xcopy will do the job and has less complexity about it